# msbuild - "This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am learning the `MSBuild` build system.

In the documentation located [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.tasks.exec.consoleoutput(v=vs.110).aspx), for example,  I keep seeing this phrase.

> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

What does it mean?

Comment: This phrase is intended to help Microsoft Support.  If you call them and say "I can't get Exec.ConsoleOutput to work properly" then they can quickly get you off the phone again with "look, the manual says that you are not supposed to use it".

Comment: @HansPassant ok. Please set it as the answer.